# How to find index of element compared to the elements around it

Tags: javascript, html

I have LI elements that look like this: `<li onclick="changeday(this)">20</li>`
in a div.days. In my javascript I take the parent of the element and then get the children of the element and put it in the variable calenderdays and console log it
`function changeday(el) {
   var calenderdays = el.parentElement.childNodes;
  console.log(calenderdays);}`
which makes a console log of

> (42) [li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth, li.anothermonth]

However if I add a .indexOf(el) like `function changeday(el) {
   var calenderdays = el.parentElement.childNodes;
  console.log(calenderdays.indexOf(el));`

> it logs VM2299 pen.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: calenderdays.indexOf is not a function
>       at changeday (VM2299 pen.js:19)
>       at HTMLLIElement.onclick (index.html?editors=1010:1)

this is despite the element definitly being in the array

> NO JQuery

Comment: can you share your pen?

Comment: You're trying to use `Array.prototype.indexOf()` on a NodeList, they're not the same thing.

Comment: Add a `console.log(calenderdays)` call and check the output. You will notice that it is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) - and not a standard array. See the linked duplicate question for how to use `indexOf` and other array methods on such lists.